# Why I can execute dispatch() method without using an instance of a Redux store(store.create())?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have been using `Redux` on some of my projects by following some tutorials, in order to make API calls(write action creators that return a function instead of an action) we use `redux-thunk.`

I don't understand why inside this action creators functions I can run `dispatch()` without having to use an instance of the store `store.dispatch()`?

*Example on the redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction):*

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])

function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    text
  }
}

store.dispatch(addTodo('Read the docs'))
store.dispatch(addTodo('Read about the middleware'))
```

*Tutorial Code:*

```
const loadRockets = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await fetch(URL);
  const data = await res.json();
  const state = data.map((rocket) => ({
    id: rocket.id,
    name: rocket.rocket_name,
    image: rocket.flickr_images[0],
    type: rocket.rocket_type,
    description: rocket.description,
    reserved: false,
  }));
  dispatch({ type: LOAD, state });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that because the redux-thunk middleware is designed to work that way. If you dispatch a function, redux-thunk will call that function and pass the dispatch function in to you. If you're curious, here is the code where they implement that (in particular, the `return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument)` part):

```
function createThunkMiddleware<
  State = any,
  BasicAction extends Action = AnyAction,
  ExtraThunkArg = undefined
>(extraArgument?: ExtraThunkArg) {
  // Standard Redux middleware definition pattern:
  // See: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#writing-custom-middleware
  const middleware: ThunkMiddleware<State, BasicAction, ExtraThunkArg> =
    ({ dispatch, getState }) =>
    next =>
    action => {
      // The thunk middleware looks for any functions that were passed to `store.dispatch`.
      // If this "action" is really a function, call it and return the result.
      if (typeof action === 'function') {
        // Inject the store's `dispatch` and `getState` methods, as well as any "extra arg"
        return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument)
      }

      // Otherwise, pass the action down the middleware chain as usual
      return next(action)
    }
  return middleware
}
```

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.ts#L30